# SQL - Conditional count

Tags: sql, database, count

I'm stuck with sql statements. I'm trying to list the name of the person who owns the most cows(female) specifying the id_person, name, species, sex and numbers of cows owned.
In animal table I have : id_animal, name_animal, species, sex, date_of_birth and in person table :  id_animal, id_person, name, adress.

```
+--------------+----------+
| id_person    | id_animal|
+--------------+----------+
| 1            | 1        | 
| 2            | 2        |
| 1            | 1        |
| 3            | 4        |
| 4            | 5        |
+--------------+----------+
```

These are the columns that interest me. I gave an example..the owner with id: 1 owns 2 cows, id: 1 in the id_animal column is assigned to the cow.

So how can I write the query to list the name of the person who owns the most cows?

The output should be  :

```
+--------------+------+----+--------------------+
| id_person    | name | sex|total_number_of_cows|
+--------------+------+----+--------------------+
| 1            | Tom  |  F | 2                  |
+--------------+------+----+--------------------+
```

I'm using DB browser for SQLite

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (1) Show the results you want.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) Explain how you know that `1` is a cow.

Comment: I don't know .. I just gave an example.. I need to check if the animal name is 'cow'  and the sex animal is 'f' then return the person...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention with RDBMS you are using, so I'll post an answer that works for SQL Server and MySql as these are common for questions on SO.  Please let me know if it's another.

Based on the sample data, you could use something like this:

```
-- MySql
SELECT id_person
  FROM animals
  GROUP BY id_person
  ORDER BY COUNT(id_animal) DESC
  LIMIT 1;

-- SQL Server
SELECT TOP 1 id_person
  FROM animals
  GROUP BY id_person
  ORDER BY COUNT(id_animal) DESC;
```

This groups each result by the person and counts the number of animals they have.  The person with the most animals only is returned.

Output:

| id_person |
| --- |
| 1 |

This has a limitation - if two or more people have the same number of animals then this will arbitrarily return only one of them (you don't know which it will be).  Perhaps if you can identify your use case in more detail then I could revise the answer to reflect what to do in these cases.

Here are working fiddles for:

- [MySql](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fx9vu4hhpqiKyVHaKhX2j4/0)
- [Sql Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=296caca7cd5ffd3668da81a69af71c56)

Comment: It works, but is returned the person with the most animals and I want to return the person with the most cows(female) .. in my table I have more animals such as cows, dogs, cats and so on..

Comment: @AlyAly12 To cater for that is as simple as adding a `WHERE` statement to the query.  If a cow is `1`, for example, add `WHERE id_animal = 1` to get only the results for cows.  Does that help?

Comment: I think I need to check if name_animal = 'cow'  and sex_animal = 'f' then return the person with the most cows..but whatever I try and change the query anyway I get errors..